# Rails check_box_tag within form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, form-for

Is it possible to pass the value of checked `check_box_tag`s within a `form_for` in Rails inside a hash?

Here is a very generic, basic version of the form:

```
<%= form_for(:object, :url => { :action => 'create', :id => params[:id]}) do |f| %>
  <p>Field_a: <%= f.text_field(:field_a) %></p>
  <p>Field_b: <%= f.text_field(:field_b) %></p>
  <p>Field_c: <%= f.text_field(:field_c) %></p>
  <p>Check boxes:</p>
    <% check_box_choices_object_array.each do |s| %>
      <%= check_box_tag(s.name, 1, false) %>
      <%= .name %><br />
    <% end %>
    <%= submit_tag("Create") %>
<% end %>
```

Outputs roughly:

```
Field_a ___________________
Field_b ___________________
Field_c ___________________
Check boxes:
[] box_a
[] box_b
[] box_c
[] box_d
[] box_e
[] box_f
[] box_g
```

My problem is that since the available check boxes aren't actual fields in the object's table in the database (i.e. I'm not using `check_box(:field)` in the form), each checked check box gets passed as an individual parameter (i.e. `"box_a" => "1", "box_b" => "1", "box_e" => "1"`). I would like them to be passed as such:

```
:checked_boxes => {"box_a" => "1", "box_b" => "1", "box_e" => "1"}
```

This way, I can access them easily with `params[:checked_boxes]`.
How do I do this, or, better yet, is there a better solution (I'm new to rails)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd get the results you want if you wrap the checkboxes iterator in a `fields_for :checked_boxes` tag - or at least get you close to the results you want.

```
<%= form_for(:object, :url => { :action => 'create', :id => params[:id]}) do |f| %>
  <p>Field_a: <%= f.text_field(:field_a) %></p>
  <p>Field_b: <%= f.text_field(:field_b) %></p>
  <p>Field_c: <%= f.text_field(:field_c) %></p>
  <p>Check boxes:</p>
    <%= f.fields_for :checked_boxes do |cb| %>
      <% check_box_choices_object_array.each do |s| %>
        <%= cb.check_box(s.name, 1, false) %>
        <%= .name %><br />
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <%= submit_tag("Create") %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I can see how this makes sense, however, I'm getting a NoMethodError `undefined method 'merge' for 1:Fixnum` for the line `<%= cb.check_box(s.name, 1, false) %>`

Comment: EDIT: Solved! I changed the `cb.check_box(s.name, 1, false)` to `cb.check_box(s.name)` and it worked! It passed every value (be it checked/1 or unchecked/0, but that's ok, maybe even better). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you can deal with no database attributes and models using `attr_accessor`

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  attr_accessor :box_a, :box_b, :box_c
end
```

This way you can call these attributes in your form.

Comment: Wouldn't this still pass each check box as a separate attribute, though? (i.e. `"field_a" => "data", "box_a" => "1", "box_c" => "1"`). I'd rather have it grouped (i.e. `"field_a" => "data", "checked_boxes" => {"box_a" => "1", "box_c" => "1"}`).

Comment: EDIT: Solved! I changed the `cb.check_box(s.name, 1, false)` to `cb.check_box(s.name)` and it worked! It passed every value (be it checked/1 or unchecked/0, but that's ok, maybe even better). Thanks a lot!

Comment: (I intended to type that comment in the other answer)